# Differentiation of the following:

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, find $h'(3)$

$f(1)=2, f'(1)=-1, g(1)=1, g'(1)=2 $

$f(2)=1, f'(2)=0.5, g(2)=3, g'(2)=0 $

$f(3)=3, f'(3)=2, g(3)=1, g'(3)=-2$

What I am getting is $-7/2$ , but I am unsure if that is true because I believe the correct answer is $-3/4$. Basically I found the derivative of $f(x)\times g(x)^{-1}$, and then plugged in the appropriate values from the list above.

Comment: Do you mean $h(x) = $ rather than $g(x) = $?

Comment: yes sorry thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the quotient rule,
$$h'(x) = \frac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2},$$
so that
$$h'(3) = \frac{g(3)f'(3) - f(3)g'(3)}{g(3)^2} = \frac{2-(-3)}{1^2} = 5.$$

Comment: sorry for being a real pain, but I realized I posted some of the values incorrectly

Comment: Well, you should be able to modify what I wrote to use the correct values...